When copying data from the Firebird 2.5.4 database, error invalid request BLR at offset 18
Windows 11 environment, Firebird 2.5.4 (64bit)
I have a program that runs the Firebird database, and from time to time I need to create a new database but copy some things from the old one (the program has such a function built-in). It worked for many years (nothing changed in the system and program) and now I get an error when copying

invalid request BLR at offset 18 function FILE_DELETE is not defined module name or entrypoint could not be found


I created a new database because I thought there was a problem with it, but it didn't help.

I reinstalled Firebird to version 2.5.9 - it didn't help.

I tried firebird 32bit - it didn't help.


Can you suggest something?

Your database has a UDF (a User-Defined Function), and your Firebird installation is missing the UDF library.

As an aside, there is no good reason to still be using Firebird 2.5.4 (March 2015). The latest Firebird 2.5 is Firebird 2.5.9 (June 2019), and Firebird 2.5 itself is end-of-life since 2019.

I know that I have 2.5.9, it's an old version, but my program won't handle the newer one.
Why could this library disappear if it was still working? there is a UDF folder and libraries in the firebird path, I didn't change anything. What should I do in such a situation?

If you didn't change anything, the UDF library would still be there. That said, the error can also mean that the library itself exists, but a dependency of the library no longer exists, so the library cannot be loaded. Execute select RDB$MODULE_NAME from RDB$FUNCTIONS where RDB$FUNCTION_NAME = 'FILE_DELETE'; and select the UDF folders listed in the UdfAccess setting for a library of that name (e.g. if it says FreeAdhocUdf, then Firebird will try to load FreeAdhocUdf.dll).
